# Downgrading Windows 8 from Enterprise to Pro

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to downgrade Windows 8 Enterprise to a Windows 8 Pro? If so, do I keep the settings (such as the Proxy Settings on the Control Panel) or do I need to reinstall my (non-metro) apps?

Comment: The other edition ID's are here https://superuser.com/questions/870769/windows-8-1-editionids

Answer (score 26):

Yes it is; it just takes a little time (it is worth it)

1. Open registry editor (run `regedit.exe`) and navigate
   to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE→SOFTWARE→Microsoft→Windows NT→CurrentVersion
2. Double click on `ProductName` and change to "Windows 8 Professional".
3. Double click `EditionID` and change to "Professional":
   [image]
4. Now navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE→SOFTWARE→WOW6432Node→Microsoft→ Windows NT→ CurrentVersion
5. Do the same as you did in steps 2 and 3.
6. Close regedit (You don't have to restart your computer).
7. Close and insert Windows 8 Pro CD and install.

---

**Editor's note:** Somebody 
who didn't have commenting privileges
[tried to edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/416999) this answer with the addendum
"You do need the install files and a product key for Windows 8.1 Pro."

Comment: Probably not worth doing so because we are talking about a fresh install. It will not take long to restore the settings. But I like the instructions so +1.

Comment: Does this method keep all existing apps, or is this a fresh install?

Comment: Would this work in the opposite direction? I.e. from Pro to Enterprise?

Comment: Someone commented in a (now deleted?) answer: *"worked for me when changing from windows 8.1 enterprise to 8.1 Pro [...] the only notable differences after it booted back up - it said professional rather than enterprise in the windows properties window and I could now install windows media center"*

Comment: This also works in windows 10. Glad it did. :)

Comment: do you need a new product key to do this

Comment: Just wanted to add my experience from 8.1 Ent to 10 Pro: I had a Windows 10 Pro Retail DVD (with key) unable to upgrade my Windows 8.1 Enterprise laptop. It only gave me the options to keep my files (not the apps), or do a fresh install (full wipe). After applying these registry changes, and rebooting, Windows 8.1 Enterprise still identified as Enterprise in the lower right corner of my desktop with the build number showing, etc. Thankfully, the Windows 10 Pro Retail now allowed me to keep my apps (it was no longer greyed out) during the upgrade. Seems to have worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not downgrade from enterprise to pro without re-installing windows. (also it would be a upgrade, as enterprise and pro are identical, [except pro also has media center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions))

If you are trying to go from Enterprise Eval to something else [here is some more information](http://www.winsupersite.com/blog/supersite-blog-39/windows8/upgrade-windows-8-enterprise-eval-nope-144330) about it.

Comment: Is it possible to qualify this statement some more? It appears accurate to say that a straightforward 'edition change' is not possible, but that some hacking as indicated in the other answer will get the job done.