# Windows 8.1 EditionIDs?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry

In Windows 8.1's registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`), there's a string (`EditionID`) that refers to the current version of Windows you're running.

What are the values for each version of Windows 8.1 (regular, Pro, Pro + Media Center)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID for the *basic Windows 8.x* is `Core`.

The ID for the *basic Windows 8.x* (Single Language) is `CoreSingleLanguage`.

[image]

The ID for *Windows 8.x Pro* is `Professional`.

The ID for *Windows 8.x Pro + MediaCenter* is `ProfessionalWMC`

The ID for *Windows 8.1 with Bing* is `ConnectedCore`.

The ID for *Windows 8.1 with Bing (Single Language)* is `CoreConnectedSingleLanguage`.

[image]

Comment: What about the `Single Language`, and `Windows 8.1 w/Bing` editions?  I was able to find half the editions but there are about 8 variations the majority dealing with low costs version of the same license ( Core )

Comment: Bing should be **ConnectedCore**, but I have no idea which ID the Single Language has

Comment: I just know there are others.  I was going to answer but the notes I thought I had wouldn't have answered the question.

Comment: @Ramhound I added the IDs for Bing

Comment: Amazing.  Your only missing one.  `Single Language` editions are likely to have an id of `CoreSingleLanuage` since they are `Windows Core` with a single language pack.  **Anyone that works this hard for a single upvote should receive more :-(**

Comment: @Ramhound ok, I can confirm the **CoreSingleLanuage** ID. I added it.