# Is there a way to downgrade Windows 10 Enterprise to Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, windows-10-upgrade

I upgraded a Windows 7 Enterprise edition to Windows 10 Enterprise. 
For some reason I am unable to activate the Windows 10 box, and 
I believe I need to downgrade it to Windows 10 Pro in order to get
the activation to happen.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to do a fresh install?

Comment: Earlier Enterprise versions of Windows cannot be upgraded and carry the license, and as such you cannot transfer your windows 7 licence to windows 10. So it is likely that when you downgrade to windows 10 pro, you will still have an unlicensed copy of windows.

Comment: Ramhound do you have a link to the other answer? 
I have been searching for it but I can't find it. 

I have a valid license for Windows 10 Pro so that is not a problem.

Comment: @Development4.0 https://superuser.com/questions/479292/downgrading-windows-8-from-enterprise-to-pro/479375#479375