# Downgrade Windows 10 Enterprise with key

Tags: windows-10

I know there are ways to downgrade Windows 10 Enterprise to Window 10 Professional with suggestions like this here: [Is there a way to downgrade Windows 10 Enterprise to Windows 10 Pro?](https://superuser.com/questions/1213966/is-there-a-way-to-downgrade-windows-10-enterprise-to-windows-10-pro)

However, I'm wondering if its just easier to enter a license key! Are there any ramifications to just entering a new license key into Windows 10 and then rebooting to activate Pro and leave Enterprise?

Also I'm aware of Enterprise being installed for a reason due to being installed by IT from a company in question however... doesn't apply here.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise wouldn’t accept a Windows 10 Professional key.

Comment: Assuming you have tested this... or is there documentation confirming this?

Comment: Well the process I referred to in my comment which I have removed because it wasn’t that helpful requires you to perform a clean install of Windows.  The process just makes it possible to do while within Windows.

Comment: Ok, so I'm probably looking at changing the registry values from Enterprise to Professional, apply fall creators update... then apply new Pro key to be successful without loosing anything then.

Comment: If there is documentation as to why this can't be done I'd like to read up on it, as from what I understand the differences aren't what they use to be as its a bitless upgrade so why not a bitless downgrade?

Comment: Microsoft simply doesn’t have a way to downgrade from Enterprise to Professional at this time. Perhaps with their newest SKU, Prodessional for Workstations that might change.  As for the process, https://superuser.com/questions/479292/downgrading-windows-8-from-enterprise-to-pro/479375#479375, but like I said it’s semi-destructive.

Comment: I'll look into Professional for Workstation, wasn't aware this is coming out. Also, if you can sum your comments up as an answer I can accept it as answered. Cheers.

Comment: I wasn’t suggesting you use that SKU, I don’t even think it’s been released at this time, and it doesn’t answer your question.  I have no answer to your question at this time.

Comment: Just looked the SKU up, definitely no reason to use it at all.

Comment: I only mentioned it because it supports going to/from Enterprise (might also be thinking of Enterprise S) but Enterprise and Education is VLK and all other versions are not hence why downgrade isn’t something Microsoft has spent much time on.

Comment: Windows 10 can change between versions without even being perceived by the user. Especially enterprise to professional. I have witnessed it myself. The new Microsoft 365 enterprise licensing allows per user upgrades to enterprise by simply applying the license through Office 365. Windows downgrades back to professional when the license is removed. The change is imperceptible and happens, from what I can tell, instantaneously - or at least during a reboot with no further delays. So, I'm not sure how that applies here, but it most certainly can seamlessly change between pro and enterprise.

Comment: In case there is any question, this is an OEM install of Win 10 pro which seamlessly upgrades to Win 10 enterprise, then seamlessly reverts back to pro when the license is removed. But, it's a new per user licensing that I believe requires 1607 and my only experience with this is with the new "Microsoft 365" enterprise per-user licensing.

Comment: You should Submit an answer